# Ionic cordova run android --prod notworking

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm running Ionic 3.7.0, when i use --prod in run i have this message:

```
[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin 
(@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova).
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\vince\Documents\app.html'
```

And in "app.component.ts" i have

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
```

Thanks for your help !

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try with "./app.html". It seems to be going to the root.